# Porting OCTAVE C++ to iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, ios, xcode, octave

i'd been surfing the web for several hours finding always the same sites and no real answer to my query. Here's the thing, i'd like to port some of the Octave functions to a iPad/iPhone app.

i'd already tried to mix C++ with Obj-C and it works like a charm BUT i haven't been able to find the right source of OCTAVE to compile at least the very core of it, i did download the source code from sourceforge.net but i'd had seen some fortran and some other languages classes but not c++ classes.

Does anyone over here had found or had worked with some C++ classes that holds the OCTAVE functions so i can port that to iOS.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Regards,

Jorge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not answer your question, but might help: If the Octave functions you are using are relatively simple, you could try using a linear algebra package such as [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/). The docs contain a [conversion sheet from Octave/MATLAB to C++](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax).

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look to it to see if it fits my needs, what i want to port basically is the linear algebra functions! regards, Jorge

Answer (score 0):

Check if the functions you need are in [Accelerate.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/miscellaneous/conceptual/iphoneostechoverview/coreoslayer/coreoslayer.html), it embeds BLAS and it's optimized for each platform.

Comment: Ok let me check that out. What i wanted to do was to have a version of octave running on an iOS device such as the iPad

Comment: I was searching pretty much the same, Android or iOS. On Android there are a few applications (namely one based on Octave and two based on jMathlib). The point is that you cannot just port the desktop program to a touch device because the interface will suck. I tried the Android programs and actually the experience was horrible, I much more prefer using the old TI-89. There's need for a well-thought UI, and I can foresee that's more likely to come on iOS than Android. I'd definitely pay for such an app.

Comment: Btw, did you see MathStudio, formerly known as SpaceTime? It does symbolic and numerical calculus (sadly it doesn't have a pseudoinverse() function), a bit pricey for the average on these platforms but the user ratings are enthusiastic. I didn't have the chance to use it but I fear the UI suffers from what I wrote in previous comments, i.e. it's not thought for touch devices.

Comment: Hi there anddam i knew i wasn't the only one looking fwd to port this project to iOS in fact some people was able to port Octave to iOS using Jail Break, but that's not the kind of solution i was looking for. I guess you last comment is the final statement for this post, it's not possible to simple port the desktop version of Octave to iOS. I was looking for some way to create a console "style" app in iOS that uses the functions of Octave, thanks for your time & answers

Comment: It took a while to find this iOS program since I couldn't remember its name. [Pi Cubed](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/pi-cubed/id311433261?mt=8) has a good UI, one that is thought for touch. I think this could be worked on to became a good numerical environment UI.