# Porting OCTAVE Griddata function to iOS

Tags: c++, objective-c, octave, scientific-computing

I'm currently working on a project, where I need to include few of Octave functions (exactly Griddata). My question is, if it's possible to use my octave code as a c++ library, which I just can include to my Objective-C project and give the input to the library, which computes the result and return the output to my project.

I already searched the web, but I couldn't find anything :/

The function i'm looking for is: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/griddata.html

Thanks

Comment: did you checked this question, it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801925/porting-octave-c-to-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can [embed the Octave interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246444/how-to-embed-the-gnu-octave-in-c-c-program) into your program and then call your Octave-function using `octave::feval`.